# Controlling the name of a forked process

Tags: fork

I'd like to have control over the name a of a process that is forked from a Perl script. Ideally it would go something like this:

```
./forker.pl
 | ...
 |
 | fork("forked.pl");
 |\
 | \
 |  `--------\
 |            \
forker.pl     forked.pl
```

...as seen by by `top` or `ps`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Good question, I don't think it is possible, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OS permits it at all,

```
$0 = 'forked.pl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Perchance can this module help you: http://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Prctl . This under the assumption that you are on a Linux platform.

Comment: The other answer was just so simple that I didn't need to look into this. It may in fact work though.